# Atualizar div somente quando os dados forem alterados

Tags: jquery

Não sei se é possível, mas estou trabalhando em cima do FullCalendar. Já consegui cadastrar e alterar a data usando o **eventDrop**, até aqui tudo certo, porém ao lado do calendário, criei uma área onde mostra os últimos 05 eventos cadastrados. Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer com que, ao arrastar um evento para outra data, atualize automaticamente a div onde trago do banco de dados os 05 últimos eventos.

Sei que usando o   **setInterval()** isso se torna possível, mas minha preocupação é que, até onde sei, o **setInterval()** acaba exigindo do servidor, por isso é possível ativar o **setInterval()**  da div somente quando a data for alterada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var t;
function temporiza() {
    t = setTimeout(function () { 

        // Atualiza o DIV

        // Caso queira que o ciclo de temporização recomece, descomente abaixo.
        //temporiza();
    }, 1000 /* aguarda 1000 ms */);
}

....

$('#calendario').fullCalendar({
    ....
    , eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertCallback) {
            ....
        if (confirm('Deseja fazer esta mudança?')) {
            // Salva o evento.

            // Atualiza o DIV.
            if (!t) temporiza();
        } else {
            revertCallback(event);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfeito. Muito obrigado Marcelo.